# iOS TableView form dimensions

Tags: ios, uitableview

In Xcode 7 I'm trying to create a form using a table view with static cells so a user can add a new item to my app.

Example of a table view form from the iOS settings menu:
[image: Add mail account table view form from iOS]

What are the dimensions and text sizes for the label and text field in a table view form? They are not listed anywhere in Apple's documentation and this seems like the cleanest way to create a form.

Comment: Can't you just use Photoshop/Gimp/Whatever and measure that with a ruler ?

Comment: I've tried measuring but don't get very consistent results and wanted to know if there was a standard across different display dimensions.

Comment: Measure is almost pointless because iPhones come into different sizes, your UI should be adaptive and accomodate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sample project online for a [storyboarding tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2) which used text fields in a UITableView.

Comparing it to measurements from iOS screenshots shows that the left and right spacing for a textfield or label is 15px and so is the spacing between multiple objects.

The font size is also 17.

[image: Spacing between items]

[image: Right spacing]

[image: Left spacing]